# Trello Command Line

Tags: api, command-line

I'm looking for a cli Trello client.  I've found several - a ruby version, multiple Python versions, and multiple Node.js versions.  They are all (or mostly all) fine, but they don't appear to allow for easy command line syntax.
They all require learning the API, and I haven't found one that simplifies the process of knowing what arguments to pass; and in what order.

I could do the whole thing with `curl`, but then I'd be in the same boat with needing to learn the API and I'd still have to parse the response `JSON`.

I started writing one myself in Node.js, but it is time consuming, and not simplistic.  What I'd like to be able to do is something like this:

`trello addCard --title 'card title' --desc 'Card description' --labels 'Green Red' --due '3/11/2017'`

Or

`trello moveCard --cardId 'cardid' --to 'listid'`

Etc - with the full Api available.  If this functionality does exist, would you provide an example(s) of usage so I get the gist?

Cmd, bash, Perl, ruby, Python, Node.js, exe, autohotkey, etc.  are all fine.

Answer (score 6):

One of these might be what you’re looking for:

[trello_cli](https://github.com/weavenet/trello_cli)

```
Usage: trello card [create] [options]
    -b, --board [BOARD]              Trello Board Id
    -d, --description [DESCRIPTION]  Description Of Card
    -l, --list [LIST]                List Of Card
    -n, --name [NAME]                Name Of Card
```

[trello-cli](https://github.com/mheap/trello-cli)

```
add-board          Adds a new board with the specified name
add-card           Add a card to a board
add-list           Adds a new list to the spcified board with the specified name
assigned-to-me     Show cards that are currently assigned to you
close-board        Closes those board(s) where the specified text occurs in their name
delete-card        Remove a card from a board
move-all-cards     Move all cards from one list to another
refresh            Refresh all your board/list names
show-boards        Show the list of cached boards
show-cards         Show the cards on a list
show-labels        Show labels defined on a board
show-list          DEPRECATED.  Show cards on a list (use 'show-cards' instead; command retained for backwards compatibility)
show-lists         Show the list of cached lists
```

[3llo](https://github.com/qcam/3llo)

```
board list
card list
card add
```

Answer (score 0):

Also if possible from [Slack](https://slack.com). So you can type:

```
/trello add @john @jessica Finish blog post
```

Here you can find more info:
https://help.trello.com/article/1049-slack-app